# how to compare old and new values for specific fields in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, map, code, business-logic

I have requirement where I need to compare few fields in account object, If there is any change in the value of any of the field I need to insert into log object.
Those fields can be change later as well. so how i can make it configurable and for now using list in class how i can compare specific fields.
Below is what i have tried so far. its working if I take field directly, but not sure how i can take field from set and check.

I need to insert record in log object if any of the value change in below fields mentioned in Set(allFields)

```
public class LogingData {
public static void getRecordDetails(list<account>accList,map<id,account>OldValues) {
    set<string> allFields = new set<String>();
    allFields.add('type');
    allFields.add('AreaNumber__c');
    allFields.add('Deadline_Date__c');
    allFields.add('CustomerPriority__c');
    map<id,account> getAccDetails = new map<id,account>();
    map<id,string> getoldvalue= new map<id,string>();
    for(account acc:accList ) {
         if(acc.type!=OldValues.get(acc.id).type){
            getoldvalue.put(acc.id,OldValues.get(acc.id).type);
            getAccDetails.put(acc.Id,acc);
        }   
        }     
    }
    insertLog(getAccDetails,getoldvalue);
}
public static void insertLog(map<id,account>accMap,map<id,string>accOldvalue) {
    list<Logs__c> piInsert = new list<Logs__c>();
    for(id ids:accMap.keyset()) {
        account acc = accMap.get(ids);
        Logs__c pi = new Logs__c();
        pi.Object_Name__c = 'Account';
        pi.Name = 'Account';    
        pi.RecordId__c = ids;
        pi.data__c = '||'+'New Value:'+acc.Type+'||'+'::::'+'||'+'Old Value'+' '+ accOldvalue.get(acc.Id)+'||';
        piInsert.add(pi);
    }
    Insert piInsert;
}
```

}

Comment: Highly recommend you use out of the box `Field History Tracking`.

Comment: thanks adrison, but the requirement is like that only. Any  suggestion

Comment: If you want to make it configurable you can create FieldSet and use it in Trigger to iterate over fields. Will it work for you?

Comment: Thanks ytiq.. Do you have any sample code..or can you please tell me how i can iterate this list to check if any value from the list has changed and create log record with that data

Comment: ok, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this. Don't forget to create `Fieldset`

```
public class LogingData {
    public static void getRecordDetails(list<account>accList, map<id, account>OldValues) {

        List<Logs__c> logs = new List<Logs__c>();
        for (account acc : accList) {
            Account oldAcc = OldValues.get(acc.Id);

            for (FieldSetMember member : SObjectType.Account.fieldSets.Compare_FieldSet.getFields()) {
                if (acc.get(member.getSObjectField()) != oldAcc.get(member.getSObjectField())) {
                    // handle changes in fields
                    buildLog(newAcc, oldAcc, member.getSObjectField());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        insert logs;
    }
    public static Logs__c buildLog(Account newAcc, Acccount oldAcc, SObjectField field) {
        return new Logs__c(
                Object_Name__c = 'Account',
                Name = 'Account',
                RecordId__c = newAcc.Id,
                data__c = '||' + field.getDescribe().getName() + 'New Value:' +  newAcc.get(field) + '||' + '::::' + '||' + 'Old Value' + ' ' + oldAcc.get(field) + '||'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ytiq,but how i can insert record in logs__c. i need to insert old value and new value in data__c  field.. like if type and industry value updated in account then  result should be || New Value : Other ||:::::: || old Values:Prospect||    || New Value : Banking||:::::: || old Values:Telecom||     etc

Comment: sure, now I get it

Comment: updated code, now it's easier to work with changes

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: Excellent..Thanks very much.it works